# How to populate youtube information into a WIX repeater?

Tags: javascript, velo

I am presently trying to populate a wix repeater with a youtube playlist via api call. I intend on adding in a video player component, but presently I cannot get anything to populate into the repeater boxes or the items I have put in them so far.

This is for a standalone custom app, so most of this work is being done from the blocks editor in WIX, for a specific widget.

I have made some code already, and it does call the playlist information but there is an unknown error between the data being populated into the repeater items.

Here is the code I am presently using:

```
import wixData from 'wix-data';

const ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 10;
let currentPage = 1;
let isLoading = false;
const DEBUG_MODE = true; // Set to false to disable debug logs

$w.onReady(function () {
    loadMoreVideos(); // Load initial set of videos
    $w('#repeater1').data = [];
    // Add event handler for repeater item ready
    $w('#repeater1').onItemReady(repeater1_itemReady);
});

async function loadMoreVideos() {
    if (!isLoading) {
        if (DEBUG_MODE) console.log('Loading more videos...');
        
        isLoading = true;
        
        const API_key = 'YOUR_YOUTUBE_API_KEY';
        const playlistId = 'YOUR_PLAYLIST_ID';
        const startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * ITEMS_PER_PAGE;

        try {
            if (DEBUG_MODE) console.log('Fetching data from YouTube API...');
            const response = await fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=${playlistId}&key=${API_key}&maxResults=${ITEMS_PER_PAGE}&startIndex=${startIndex}`);
            const data = await response.json();
            
            if (DEBUG_MODE) console.log('Data fetched successfully:', data);
            
            if (data.items) {
                const videos = data.items.map(item => ({
                    videoId: item.snippet.resourceId.videoId,
                    title: item.snippet.title,
                    thumbnailUrl: item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url
                }));
                
                if (DEBUG_MODE) console.log('Videos extracted from data:', videos);
                
                const currentData = $w('#repeater1').data;
                $w('#repeater1').data = currentData.concat(videos);
                currentPage++;
                
                if (DEBUG_MODE) console.log('Videos loaded successfully.');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error loading videos:', error);
        }

        isLoading = false;
    }
}

// Repeater item ready event handler
function repeater1_itemReady($item, itemData, index) {
    $item('#text1').text = `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${itemData.videoId}`;
    // Populate other elements with video information
    $item('#text2').text = itemData.title;
    $item('#imageX1').src = itemData.thumbnailUrl;
}
```

Comment: "there is an unknown error" ... not helpful. What is the error as reported by console/dev tools? Or how does Wix expect any sort of debugging to get done?

Comment: @GetSet there is no innate wix debugging, and I am uncertain of where an issue may be occurring even with my own degree of dubugging so far.

Comment: Do you know how to open browser dev tools? Should be accessible from your browser's menu. In chrome it would be under More Tools > Developer Tools, for example. Once open, switch to the console tab. Javascript reported errors will show there.

Comment: @GetSet WIX additionally makes this very difficult as it floods the console with false API calls through wix, this is less of a JS concern as it is specifically a WIX development concern.

Comment: I take it you just found out from my last comment on how to open the dev tools. .... Now that thats out the way, yes ignore any superfluous error messages in the console that are worth ignoring. Place statements in your code like `console.log("step 1")` etc so that you can follow along in the console of when your code is executing.

Comment: @GetSet thank you for the assistance, I am well aware of how to use dev tools, however WIX is a poorly functioning system, I am looking for specific assistance with WIX that it is clear you have no experience with. Thank you.

Comment: Just curious how you already know its a WIX problem (which agreed, sucks) when you dont know what the problem is? Hence the need to debug.